# What is the effective physical difference between a massive region of a polarized vacuum and a region of curved space-time?

Tags: general-relativity

What is the *effective* physical difference between a large region of curved space-time and an equally large region of a polarized vacuum?  Consider the fact that vacuum polarization amounts to an effective deviation in speed of light in a local region due to the deviation in electric permittivity of free space.

Comment: why would anyone downvote this great question?  General relativity can be formulated as vacuum polarization: http://arxiv.org/ftp/gr-qc/papers/9909/9909037.pdf, but I don't understand well enough to answer the question